# Distribution of polynomials mod 1 using co-prime integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

If  $a$ is any real  irrational, then the set of numbers of the form $ax+y$ with $x$ and $y$ co-prime integers is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I managed to prove this, in what I suspect is an overly complicated way,  in response to
[this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70035/searching-for-an-inhomogeneous-diophantine-approximation-algorithm/70150#70150) question.

I think there must be a more perspicuous proof of this fundamental fact. Furthermore, I expect that the following more general assertion is true:

If $f\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is any polynomial at least one of whose coefficients other than the constant term is irrational, then the numbers of the form $f(x)+y$ with $x$ and $y$ co-prime integers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now it seems to me that this ought to be a very well known fact or open problem (or maybe it is false!) but I can't find a single reference to it. Can anyone provide a proof or a reference?

Comment: I don't see any particular reason for this to be a very well known fact. The coprime condition doesn't seem very natural to me.

Comment: Isn't this a consequence of Kronecker's (or Weyl or someone's) theorem on the equidistribution of fractional parts of integral multiples of an irrational number?

Comment: @Avenger: The statement about polynomials (without the coprimality requirement) was first proved by Hardy and Littlewood. Shortly thereafter, Weyl's criterion on uniform distribution appeared, from which one can deduce a stronger result (uniform distribution mod 1, not merely density). But I don't see anything in either of these approaches that I can use to address the problem at hand.

Comment: Does "one of whose coefficients" mean "at least one" or "exactly one"?

Comment: @Gerry: I mean "at least one".

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Perhaps a geometric statement seems more "natural"? For example, are there reals $a<b$ such that the region $a<\sqrt{2}x^2-y<b$ has no integer points visible from the origin?

Comment: I should think the key is that the coprime case follows from the case where this requirement is dropped. I suppose this is how the already provided answer proceeds. Note, though, that without the coprime requirement, this is essentially saying that the fractional part of $ax$ for $a \in \mathbb{N}$ is dense in $(0,1)$. This seems clearly true, and is, of course, known (e.g. Lemma 1 in: Hedman, S., & Rose, D. (2009). Light subsets of N with dense quotient sets. The American Mathematical Monthly, 116(7), 635-641.)

Answer (score 3):

The [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for $a$ gives rational approximations $$\frac{p_i}{q_i} \approx a$$ with $|q_ia-p_i| \lt \frac1{q_i}$. Furthermore,  successive approximants satisfy $p_{i+1}q_q-p_iq_{i+1}=\pm1.$

Fix an index $i$ and consider the sequence of expressions $$r_k=x_ka+y_k=(q_{i-1}+kq_{i})a-(p_{i-1}+kp_{i})$$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. The values $r_k$ form a two way infinite arithmetic progression with common difference  $q_ia-p_i \lt \frac{1}{q_{i}}$ and thus allow us to approximate any desired real to an accuracy of better than $\frac{1}{2q_i}$. It remains only to note that

- The denominators $q_i$ increase (exponentially) and thus allow us to get any accuracy we desire.
- $x_{k+1}y_k-x_{k}y_{k+1}=p_{i+1}q_i-p_iq_{i+1}=\pm1$ so the pairs $(x_k,y_k)$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Why are $a$ and $b$ coprime? And why is $ax+b$  close to $a'x+b'$? I like your idea of perturbing an approximation to get co-primality, but a bit of detail would be very helpful here.

Comment: I changed the notation to match that of the question (though it makes your comment harder to follow) and simplified/corrected the proof while adding a few more details.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like "the" way to do it. In terms of Farey fractions your idea is to trap $\alpha$ between succesive fractions $a/b$ and $c/d$ with large denominator. Coprimality is preserved by taking mediants $(a+kc)/(b+kd)$  but the values of $\alpha (b+kd)−(a+kc)$ will form an arithmetic progression with small common difference. Pity that this doesn't generalize (as far as I can see) to polynomials of degree greater than 1.